# 403 daily quota for Google Translation API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I followed the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart) for working with Google Translate API. I have:

1. created a project
2. enabled billing and have $300 on the billing account
3. enabled the translation API and made sure that the quota is high
4. generated a service account with an Admin role and downloaded the JSON
5. added the following line to my .zshrc:

   ```
   export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/pathto/Holodeck-421412.json
   ```
6. Sourced it with:

   ```
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```

Yet both my nodeJS code and my curl return:

```
 code: 403,
  errors:
   [ { message: 'Daily Limit Exceeded',
       domain: 'usageLimits',
       reason: 'dailyLimitExceeded' } ],
  response: undefined,
  message: 'Daily Limit Exceeded' }
```

My curl:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer `gcloud auth print-access-token`" --show-error -s "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2" -d @translate-request.json
```

and translate-request.json:

```
{
  "q": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
  "source": "en",
  "target": "es",
  "format": "text"
}
```

My NodeJS code:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const language = require('@google-cloud/language');
const Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');

// Instantiates a client
const client = new language.LanguageServiceClient();

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'myproject ID';

// Instantiates a client
const translation = new Translate({
    projectId: projectId
});


// The text to analyze
let text1 = 'Hello, world!';

const translate = (text) => {
    const target = 'en';

    translation
        .translate(text, target)
        .then(results => {
            const translation = results[0];

            console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
            console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
}


const analyze = (text) => {

    const document = {
        content: "good very good amazingly good",
        type: 'PLAIN_TEXT',
    };

// Detects the sentiment of the text
    client
        .analyzeSentiment({document: document})
        .then(results => {
            const sentiment = results[0].documentSentiment;
            console.log(`Sentiment score: ${sentiment.score}`);
            console.log(`Sentiment magnitude: ${sentiment.magnitude}`);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
}

translate(text1);
analyze(text1);
```

It is puzzling to me as the Natural Language API is working so the Service account seems to be functioning properly. Any angle on this? I am 3 hours deep trying to pass this unexpected hurdle and I've done any yak shaving I could think off including opening new projects / service account / API keys and google groups forums (which it's design just make me appreciate StackOverflow more... :))

**----UPDATE----**

When I change the quota of **Characters per day** from 1,000,000 to another value the API seems to start working for 15 or so seconds (2-3 requests) and then goes back to the 403 error. Then if I change the quota again I get another round of 2-3 requests. It is as if the request itself is changing the quota or the change is undone after 15-20 seconds.

[image: quota]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should have been Fixed as of now, please try again to see if you're still seeing this issue and re-open the Issue [#70990743](https://issuetracker.google.com/70990743) if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue and searching I found this bug in the Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70990743

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem with quotas. You should increase "character per day" and "character per second".